# Algolia filtering by partial match

Tags: reactjs, algolia

how to implement filtering in Algolia by partial match. In `fruits: 'apple, banana'` (field in algolia). Filter: `"fruits:apple"`

I expect to get all records when fruits field contains apple (not only apple but apple with other fruits)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array in your index to have this behavior.

So instead of `fruits: 'apple, banana'`, use `fruits: ['apple', 'banana']`.